# Is there any good GMAP.NET documentation out there for C# Windows Form?

Tags: google-maps, gmap.net

I'm currently using this link as a guide. It is been great but I would like to be able to view class documentation. Does it exist somewhere? I have been unable to find any.
[Link](http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-beginners-tutorialadding-polygons-and-routes-to-your-map-updated-for-visual-studio-2015-and-gmap-net-1-7/)

Answer (score 3):

The development is still active and since the author is sharing his sources, your most recent bet is the [github project page](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps). Try to build the sample app, it gives quite good insights.

For older issues and follow up on the development road this project has taken also consider the [soon to be closed codeplex page](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/).

Also, notice that you can obtain the [package via nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/1.7.0), in case you're using nuget as your package manager.

At last ask questions here, there are a few fellows around that are happily helping out!

Comment: Thank you for your help. So in short, there is not any document or site that contains all the information that I might need. Hopefully it comes soon. I've been able to find answers to most of my questions up to this point by searching the internet... which is quite tedious. I will be sure to ask more questions in the near future. Like how to get my markers and text to display on top of the route lines.